# Optimize react-redux store using useSelector and useDispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, reselect

I am using `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks from `react-redux` library to connect to store in my RN app.

Here's a small example:

```
const dashboard = useSelector((state: IDashboardState) => state.dashboard);
const { isCollectionsLoading, collections, collectionsError } = dashboard;

const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getCollection());
}, []);
```

The dashboard state is quite large and it has a lot more fields. Since I need only 3 of them for this very screen, is there any way to optimize the state and not to overcomplicate the logic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can you [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect) library to select data from the store in a performant way.

Here is an aligator article regarding this: [article](https://alligator.io/redux/reselect/)